# Unresolved reference 'BeautifulSoup'

Tags: python, python-2.7, intellij-idea

I ran into a problem Unresolved reference 'BeautifulSoup'. I have already installed BeautifulSoup but still it shows unresolved.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

OS: Mac

IDE: IntelliJ

Python: 2.7.10

```
pip list

altgraph (0.10.2)
bdist-mpkg (0.5.0)
BeautifulSoup (3.2.1)
bonjour-py (0.3)
click (6.6)
Flask (0.11.1)
Flask-Psycopg2 (1.3)
Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.1)
flatlib (0.2.1)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.8)
macholib (1.5.1)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
matplotlib (1.3.1)
modulegraph (0.10.4)
numpy (1.8.0rc1)
pip (8.1.2)
psycopg2 (2.6.2)
py2app (0.7.3)
pyobjc-core (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Accounts (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Automator (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreData (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreText (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-EventKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Message (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-PubSub (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-QTKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Quartz (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Social (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-WebKit (2.5.1)
pyOpenSSL (0.13.1)
pyparsing (2.0.1)
pyswisseph (2.0.0.post2)
python-dateutil (1.5)
pytz (2013.7)
requests (2.11.1)
scipy (0.13.0b1)
setuptools (1.1.6)
six (1.4.1)
SQLAlchemy (1.0.14)
Werkzeug (0.11.10)
xattr (0.6.4)
zope.interface (4.1.1)
```

Comment: check you interpretation configuration in IDE, it might use something different.

Comment: your beautiful soup version is `3.2.1` and you used in your syntax `from bs4`.....that's why it is not showing...either use `from bs3` / `from bs` or upgrade your beautiful soup version

Comment: Thanks Fixed by `pip install BeautifulSoup4`

Answer (score 1):

Install the new BeautifulSoup version

On your terminal:

```
pip3 install bs4
```

or

```
pip install bs4
```